# How to post under a page in Blogger

Tags: blogger

I have multiple pages in my blog. Now I want to post in different page.

Example:

```
Page 1: Local
Page 2: National
Page 3: International

Post 1: Local Topic 1
Post 2: National Topic 1
Post 2: International Topic 1

Post 1 needs to be under Page 1
Post 2 needs to be under Page 2
Post 3 needs to be under Page 3
```

Comment: Pages are 'static', you can't post on a page. Use labels to post under a topic and have the link for the label added to your page tab or anywhere you like.

Answer (score 1):

Blogger isn't a great system to work with to do this. The link above is one way. Another (which I found simpler for my purposes) was to publish to my home feed, but set the date of the post to some time significantly in the past so the posts are buried underneath my more recent posts. Then, I link my posts to the new page in the order they occurred. I hope this gives people another option!

Answer (score 1):

It can be posted with the help of labels.
Let's say you have Label named "Topic" and want to post on "Local" page. So process is;

Click on "Topic" label, copy the label URL from main search bar.
Go to Blogger dashboard > Pages > New page > Web address
Mention "Local" in page title column and paste copied URL in web address (URL) column
click on Save.

Now, you can see the all posts in "Local" page which are having "Topic" label.
Whenever, you want to post in "Local" give a "Topic" label name to the post and publish, it will be shown there.

This process can be applied for all pages mentioned in question.
Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

That's not really how Pages work in Blogger.

But you can achieve what you want, using labels, and the labels gadget instead of the pages one.  I've described it more fully [here](http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.com/2010/12/how-to-put-put-posts-into-your-pages-in.html).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if I post an answer here and Blogger later changes how it does things, then my answer here becomes out-of-date and incorrect - and it's not viable for me to go back and change every single place where I've posted the answer.
Whereas if I post a link, then I can control the content on the linked sources, and just update one place to make my answer correct again.
Personally I prefer this approach, as it doesn't see my name put beside out-of-date information over time.

Comment: Maybe, but it flies in the face of how the Stack Exchange sites work. When that link stops working, this answer has no value whatsoever.

Comment: Really?  "But you can achieve what you want, using labels, and the labels gadget instead of the pages one" sounds to me like a short summary of what is explained in the link, without getting into detail about things that are likely to change.

Comment: If the answer becomes out of date, it needs to updated which *can* be done by you or any member of the community. The more detailed and up to date the answer, the more valuable it can be to someone who crosses it. Most users update their answers as time passes by. And if they (the community and visitors) would like to know the source, by all means, they can go back to your blog :) See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion for more info.